# Matlab help, add string at the end of each cell in a array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I am new to Matlab. I would like to know how to write a string at the end of each cell in a cell array. For ex `data(cell array) = [QAN ASX BHP RIO........ ]` I would like this to appear `[QAN.ax BHP.ax RIO.ax....]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [STRCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html) function:

```
newdata = strcat(data,'.ax');
```